# How to I update a pre-existing leaderboard text file, making sure it's sorted?

Tags: c++, file

First of I'd like to thank you all in advance for taking your time reading and helping me with my problem. I'm in no way shape or form an expert at c++, I'm not even good. I started programming in c++ 2 months ago and I find it quite harder than python, for a second experience with programming languages.
So I'm making this game for my programming class and I have to have a leaderboard text file with all the winners of a certain level. I set it up so the file always has the same format for time, name like this.

[image]

I've been trying to figure out how to sort the leaderboard entries by time and then by name. I thought of reading the file from line 3 and beyond but that doesn't seem to work. I moved on to what seems a better way of doing it which is to read the whole leaderboard discarding the first 2 lines, store it line by line on a vector, sorting the vector then and wiping the file by opening it in trunc mode but for some reason the file doesn't get wiped, it just keeps on adding more and more entries. I wan't it to add the sorted lines (vector) to the leaderboard one by one up until 10 entries are hit. Can someone help me? Here's a code sniped with the function I'm using to update the leaderboard

```
// Function to check if MAZE_XX_WINNERS.txt exists, if not creates it
void makeLeaderboard(string maze_name, string formated_time){
    
    string winner_name, filename = maze_name.substr(0,7) +"_WINNERS.txt";

    while(true){

        // If MAZE_XX_WINNERS.txt file exists
        if(ifstream(filename)){

            // Open MAZE_XX_WINNERS.txt file in append mode
            fstream leaderboard(filename, fstream::app);

            // Ask for player name
            cout << "Type your name (max 15 characters): ";
            getline(cin, winner_name);

            // If name is valid
            if(isValidName(winner_name) && winner_name.length() <= 15){
                
                string line;
                vector<string> lb_entries;
                int n_line = 0;

                // Append to the end of the file
                leaderboard << formated_time << " - " << winner_name << endl;

                // Store all leaderboard entries in a vector
                while(!leaderboard.eof()){

                    if(n_line >= 2){
                        getline(leaderboard, line);
                        lb_entries.push_back(line);
                    }
                    n_line++;
                }
                leaderboard.close();

//Everything works up until here, past here it doesn't do anything I want it to do

                // Sort the leaderboard entries first by time, then by name
                sort(lb_entries.begin(), lb_entries.end());

                // Check if leaderboard has more than 10 entries to delete those past the limit
                if(lb_entries.size() > 10){
                    
                    // Truncates the vector from the 10th position forward
                    lb_entries.erase(lb_entries.begin()+9, lb_entries.end());
                }

                // Reopens the file in truncation mode to delete pre-existing leaderboard
                leaderboard.open(filename, fstream::trunc);

                // Format the file to have a table like shape
                leaderboard << "|    TIME    -      NAME     |" << endl;
                leaderboard << "------------------------------" << endl;

                // Updates leaderboard
                for(string entry : lb_entries){
                    leaderboard << entry << endl;
                }
                
                leaderboard.close();
                break;
            }
            // If name not valid
            else if(isValidName(winner_name) && winner_name.length() > 15){
                cerr << endl << "Name has more than 15 characters! Please retry." << endl << endl;
            }
            else{
                cerr << endl << "Not a valid name input!" << endl << endl;
            }
        }
        // If file doesn't exist
        else{

            // Attempt to create the file
            cout << "Creating leaderboard..." << endl;
            ofstream leaderboard(filename);

            // Check if file was created
            if(!leaderboard){
                cerr << "File could not be created" << endl;
            }
            else{

                // Format the file to have a table like shape
                leaderboard << "|    TIME    -      NAME     |" << endl;
                leaderboard << "------------------------------" << endl;

                leaderboard.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to [open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) a file with just `trunc` as the openmode will fail. It needs to be paired with `out` . You're also not reading the file in, because you open it, append the new record, then try to read the existing records. This won't read anything because you'll be reading from the end of the file, having just written there.

Comment: sorry I didn't quite get what you're telling me to do, can you give me some examples of code so I can compare and learn from my mistakes?

Comment: Ok I finally understood what you meant after some trial and error. I swapped this line of code ```leaderboard.open(filename, fstream::trunc);```with this one ```leaderboard.open(filename, fstream::trunc | fstream::out | fstream::app);``` but now I have another issue. The program is now taking what's there and updating it's contents by sorting the leaderboard or preventing more than 10 entries. It's just adding stuff at the bottom. I feel like I'm going backwards

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your problem down. What I would do is create a class that represents the LeaderBoards. It would actually consist of two classes. You could do one as an inner class of the others, but let's keep them separate:

```
class Leader {
public:
     std::string time;
     std::string name;
};

class LeaderBoard {
public:
     std::vector<Leader> leaders;
     void readFromFile(std::string fName);
     void sort();
     void writeToFile(std::string fName);
};
```

At that point, you need to implement three functions. None of them are very long.

```
void LeaderBoard::readFromFile(std::string fName) {
    std::ifstream file(fName);
    std::string line;

    // skip the header
    file.getline(line);
    file.getline(line);

    // Read the rest of the file.
    while (file.getline(line)) {
         // You'll need to parse the line into its parts
         Leader leader(from the parts);
         leaders.push_back(leader);
    }
}
```

Yeah, I left some magic for you.

The write method would be very simple and just use an ofstream instead of an ifstream.

The sort method -- you can do a google for "c++ sort vector of objects" and get LOTS of examples.

---

In general, ALL programming can be broken down into smaller steps. If you're getting overwhelmed, break it down. This is one of the reasons you use an object-oriented language. If you don't know how to do something, create a class for it, then put methods in it for the smaller steps.

Then just figure out how to do small parts at a time. First: get data. Then print it out so you're sure you've got what you need.

If your code is more than about a screen or so, you're doing too much in one method. That's not an absolute, but at your level of coding, it's definitely true.

Small, tight methods. Small, tight methods are easier to write. Then string them together.

In this case:

1. Read the data
2. Sort the data
3. Write the data.

Each of these is easy to test individually.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I really appreciate it and will try to use it as much as possible to improve. Regarding your solution to my problem: We opted to leave Classes and structures out since we just started learning the language. We'll move onto harder concepts after the project is finished. I think I'll be able to take what you thought me and tweak it to fit in a function instead of a Class, though.